# Capture multiple rows in the last single insert action and select from them without using triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following insert action :

```
declare @appName varchar(35), @modName varchar(125), @cnt int;
select @cnt=0;
BEGIN TRY
    insert into dbo.AppsMonitor (
        AppName, AppLoadTime, AppLastUpdate, ModName, ModLoadTime, ModLastUpdate , ModErrMsg
    )
    SELECT
        _Scanner.value('@scannerName'   ,   'varchar(25)') AS scannerName
        , _Scanner.value('@StartAt' ,   'varchar(22)') AS LoadTime
        , _Scanner.value('@LastUpdate'  ,   'varchar(22)') AS LastUpdate

        , _Module.value('@modName'  ,   'varchar(125)') AS ModName
        , _Module.value('@StartAt'  ,   'varchar(22)') AS LoadTime
        , _Module.value('@LastUpdate'   ,   'varchar(22)') AS LastUpdate

        , _Module.value('ErrMsg[1]' ,   'varchar(500)') AS ErrMsg
    FROM @xml.nodes('/AllMyScanners/Scanners/Scanner') 
                        As AllMyScanners(_Scanner)  
    CROSS APPLY _Scanner.nodes('Modules/Module') 
                        AS Modules(_Module)
    select @cnt=@@ROWCOUNT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    set @rr=-2;
    print 'Err#4'
END CATCH
```

I want to select some fields from the inserted buffer (something like @@inserted) what I have just inserted into the table dbo.AppsMonitor for analytical purpose.

How to do that without using triggers?  My team does not allow triggers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with an [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). Use `OUTPUT INSERTED.xxx`

Comment: It's a little bit tricky for INSERTED. The syntax is a little bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Amit for your answer. TO make it more clear for other readers, my code using OUTPUT for INSERTED is

```
BEGIN TRY
    insert into dbo.AppsMonitor (
        AppName, AppLoadTime, AppLastUpdate, ModName, ModLoadTime, ModLastUpdate , ModErrMsg
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.AppName, INSERTED.ModName into @tmpVar 
    SELECT
        _Scanner.value('@scannerName'   ,   'varchar(25)') AS scannerName
        , _Scanner.value('@StartAt' ,   'varchar(22)') AS LoadTime
        , _Scanner.value('@LastUpdate'  ,   'varchar(22)') AS LastUpdate

        , _Module.value('@modName'  ,   'varchar(125)') AS ModName
        , _Module.value('@StartAt'  ,   'varchar(22)') AS LoadTime
        , _Module.value('@LastUpdate'   ,   'varchar(22)') AS LastUpdate

        , _Module.value('ErrMsg[1]' ,   'varchar(500)') AS ErrMsg
    FROM @xml.nodes('/AllMyScanners/Scanners/Scanner') 
                        As AllMyScanners(_Scanner)  
    CROSS APPLY _Scanner.nodes('Modules/Module') 
                        AS Modules(_Module)
    select @cnt=@@ROWCOUNT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    set @rr=-2;
    print 'Err#4'
END CATCH
```